# mysqldump not found (Wordmove). How to correctly set up a symlink in Zsh?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, zsh, symlink

I have searched through related questions but have still not found an answer to this one.

I am using Wordmove to try and push/pull databases between local and live environments for WordPress (running on AMPPS on OSX). I have come back to trying the Wordmove method since the fork of WP-Sync-DB stopped working for me and appears to be abandoned now. This was the best free method for migrating databases between WordPress environments.

The error I am getting when running `wordmove pull -e runcloud --db` is `sh: mysqldump: command not found`

I am using Zsh and have already added a symlink to the only mysqldump I could locate on my system: `alias mysqldump='/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin/mysqldump --host=localhost -uroot -proot'` in .zprofile . It is also included in my .bash_profile . Without that line I simply get `mysqldump not found` (verified by commenting the line and needing to restart iTerm after each change).

So now if I type `which mysqldump` I get `mysqldump: aliased to /Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin/mysqldump --host=localhost -uroot -proot`

But the error from Wordmove persists. I have enquired on the Wordmove Github and the author says this will be an error with how mysqldump if configured.

Disclaimer: I am not at all expert with CLI, only knowing enough to configure an environment for Gulp, using tools like Wordmove and basic stuff over SSH. I chose Zsh as it made a lot of stuff easier to use and to see, but any kind of configuration for this usually has me scratching my head!

Have I missed something obvious here? Perhaps the symlink is not set up correctly?

Comment: An alias and a symlink are two entirely different things. I suspect the problem is that aliases aren't expanded in shell scripts by default, only in interactive shells.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I don't understand this well enough to proceed without finding some kind of walkthrough or tutorial.

Comment: @chepner: alias works fine in non-interactive Zsh as well. See my answer for what I think is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

I see two conceptual problems here:

(1) You can not export an alias. An alias defined in the current Zsh, won't be automtaically be visible in a child Zsh.

(2) Your error message says

*sh: mysqldump: command not found*

which means that Zsh is not even involved when looking for mysqldump. This is a Posix shell script running.

Hence, every mechanism you want to use must work with Posix shell, which means that you need a program (a suitable shell script) named `mysqldump` in your PATH, which then calls the original `mysqldump` with the parameters you have in mind.

Make sure that the PATH is set up so that your private version of `mysqldump` is found before the one in /Applications/AMPPS/mysql/bin.

Comment: Thanks for this, it makes sense.
For some reason I had no other mysql installed.
Is it not possible to tell bash to reference the AMPPS mysql?
This instance will be running when I want to do the Wordmove translation(push/pull).
Another instance would also need to be stopped and started manually?

Comment: For now I installed mysql (directly from the pkg installer) and verified that it exists at
usr/local(alias)/mysql 

The contents of my .bash_profile are:

`ssh-add -A 2>/dev/null;
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin`

Comment: With 'which mysql' I still either get 'mysql: aliased to nocorrect mysql', or mysqlnotfound with 'unalias mysql' added at the end of .zshrc